# Batch script to replace PHP short open tags with <?php

Tags: php, sed, find, awk

I have a large collection of php files written over the years and I need to properly replace all the short open tags into proper explicit open tags.

```
change "<?" into "<?php"
```

I think this regular expression will properly select them :

```
<\?(\s|\n|\t|[^a-zA-Z])
```

which takes care of cases like

```
<?//
<?/*
```

but I am not sure how to process a whole folder tree and detect the .php file extension and apply the regular expression and save the file after it has been changed.

I have the feeling this can be pretty straightforward if you master the right tools. (There is an interesting hack in the sed manual: [4.3 Example/Rename files to lower case](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Rename-files-to-lower-case)).

Maybe I'm wrong.
Or maybe this could be a oneliner?

Comment: Does your script handle <?= (the equivalent of <?php echo)?

Comment: No it does not (as far as I remember), but I guess it would be good to take this syntax into account, in order to get a solution useful for anybody.

Answer (score 16):

don't use regexps for parsing formal languages - you'll always run into haystacks you did not anticipate. like:

```
<?
$bla = '?> now what? <?';
```

it's safer to use a processor that knows about the structure of the language. for html, that would be a xml processor; for php, the built-in [tokenizer extension](http://php.net/tokenizer). it has the [`T_OPEN_TAG`](http://php.net/tokens) parser token, which matches `<?php`, `<?` or `<%`, and [`T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO`](http://php.net/tokens), which matches `<?=` or `<%=`. to replace all short open tags, you find all these tokens and replace `T_OPEN_TAG` with `<?php` and `T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO` with `<?php echo` .

the implementation is left as an exercise for the reader :)

**EDIT 1**: ringmaster was so kind to [provide one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684587/batch-script-to-replace-php-short-open-tags-with-php/1647429#1647429).

**EDIT 2**: on systems with [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) turned off in `php.ini`, `<?`, `<%`, and `<?=` won't be recognized by a replacement script. to make the script work on such systems, enable `short_open_tag` via command line option:

```
php -d short_open_tag=On short_open_tag_replacement_script.php
```

p.s. [the man page for token_get_all()](http://php.net/token-get-all) and googleing for creative combinations of *tokenizer*, *token_get_all*, and the parser token names might help.

p.p.s. see also [Regex to parse define() contents, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645862/regex-to-parse-define-contents-possible/645957) here on SO

Comment: You definitely have a point here. I need to check this out. (Although I must say I hardly imagine where I would want to echo "<?" without appending "php" anyway)

Comment: @Polypheme: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: @Piskvor: yes you are right, but I take care of this in the regex I use. Ok my remark between brackets was just a guess. And I guess that in approximately 100% of *my* cases the string situation would not be a problem. The "tokens route" is still better/cleaner though.

Comment: While this process is possibly a better alternative to using regex, note that it does not work on the system with short tags turned off, since the tokenizer obeys the settings in the php.ini for short tags.

Comment: @ringmaster: with short tags off in php.ini, you just do a `ini_set('short_open_tag', 1)` before calling the tokenizer, can't you?

Comment: @ringmaster: you are right: it doesn't work w/ `ini_set`. thinking about it, this makes sense, as this setting is used early, in the parsing phase, before any code, including `ini_set`, has ever been executed. i thought it would work because it is documented as `PHP_INI_ALL` - this apparently is a (documentation) bug.

there is a way around this, though: just set `short_open_tag` to On/1 via command line option, like so:

    php -d short_open_tag=On test.php

then it *is* applied before the parsing state, and your tag replacement script works on systems with short tags turned off, too.

Comment: "the implementation is left as an exercise for the reader :)" altought is an interesing question... it doesn't really solve any problem..

Comment: @levhita trying to solve an exercise by yourself makes you better, because you understand. just copying the result of someone else' work from a google search doesn't. nor does complaining and downvoting a hint that might help you help yourself.

Comment: @ax I'm afraid this is place to find answers not more questions... although there is people here just learning some of us had been doing this for over decade and just need to make things work.

Everything you said is absolutely true and I recommend that myself when I teach at my local university, just not correct for the most common user case of the stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using the tokenizer option, this might be helpful:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$tokens = token_get_all($content);
$output = '';

foreach($tokens as $token) {
 if(is_array($token)) {
  list($index, $code, $line) = $token;
  switch($index) {
   case T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO:
    $output .= '<?php echo ';
    break;
   case T_OPEN_TAG:
    $output .= '<?php ';
    break;
   default:
    $output .= $code;
    break;
  }

 }
 else {
  $output .= $token;
 }
}
return $output;
```

Note that the tokenizer will not properly tokenize short tags if short tags aren't enabled.  That is, you can't run this code on the system where short tags aren't working.  You must run it elsewhere to convert the code.

Comment: see my last comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684587/batch-script-to-replace-php-short-open-tags-with-php/684752#684752 for how to make it work on systems with `short_open_tag = Off`, too.

Answer (score 11):

The problem has been solved as a *fixer* in the `php-cs-fixer`  tool which can be easily installed and which is tested and maintained.

Fixing then is easy:

```
$ php-cs-fixer fix <path> --rules=full_opening_tag,no_short_echo_tag --diff --dry-run
```

Just replace *`<path>`* with the path to the directory or file you'd like to change. The command as given is to review first (`--dry-run`  and `--diff` parameters).

Installing [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) is as easy as

```
$ composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

if you've got composer installed with global composer bin directory in your path (recommended).

Comment: Latest version of php-cs-fixer uses this syntax: ```php-cs-fixer fix --rules=full_opening_tag --diff --dry-run .```

Comment: This with the best answer, especially if you adopt https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer as a linter to keep your project clean long term.

Answer (score 4):

This is a utility I wrote that converts PHP source that contains short open tags and replaces them with long tags.

- https://github.com/danorton/php_replace_short_tags

i.e. it converts code like this:

```
  <?= $var1 ?>
  <? printf("%u changes\n",$changes) ?>
```

To this

```
  <?php echo $var1 ?>
  <?php printf("%u changes\n",$changes) ?>
```

The **--skip-echo-tags** option will cause it to skip **<?=** tags and only replace **<?** tags.

It’s written as a PHP-CLI script and needs the CLI **php.ini** file to be set to permit short short open tags. That’s the default setting for PHP 5.3.0 and earlier, but it might not always remain so. (The script simply won’t change anything if the setting isn’t enabled.)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: The link is dead again. Mind updating it / putting the script somewhere stable?

Comment: the problem is this script doesn't handle a full directory, which is what the question asked for...and really why you'd need a script to do this in the first place.

Comment: For processing all files in the current directory you can use `php php_replace_short_tags.php --overwrite *` (this overwrites the files) and if you want it recursively this solution might help: https://github.com/danorton/php_replace_short_tags/issues/4

Comment: `<?=` is not a short open tag, and it is not deprecated; thus will not be removed

Answer (score 3):

My previous answer I just overwrote with sed wont work, sed is too weak for this sort of thing IMO.

So I've whipped up a perl-script that should do the trick, its hopefully very user-editable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;
use Carp;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.php')->in('/tmp/foo/bar');

for my $file (@files) {
    rename $file, $file . '.orig';
    open my $output, '>', $file or Carp::croak("Write Error with $file $! $@ ");
    open my $input, '<', $file . '.orig'
      or Carp::croak("Read error with $file.orig $! $@");

    while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
        # Replace <?= with <?php echo 
        $line =~ s/<\?=/<?php echo /g;

        # Replace <? ashded  with <?php ashed

        $line =~ s/<\?(?!php|xml)/<?php /g;
        print $output $line;
    }

    close $input  or Carp::carp(" Close error with $file.orig, $! $@");
    close $output or Carp::carp(" Close error with $file  , $! $@");

    unlink $file . '.orig';
}
```

But note, I haven't tested this on any real code, so It could go "Bang" .

I would recommend you have your code revisioned ( wait, its already revisioned, right? .. right? )  and run your test-suite ( Don't tell me you don't have tests ! ) on the modified code, because you can't be *certain* its doing the right thing without a fully fledged FSM parser.

Comment: uhm, will this not make my site fuzzy if i have inline codes like <?=$printme;?> ???

Comment: Thank you Kent Fredric, this gives me an idea on how to link find results and a sed command. But I'm afraid we're not there yet.

Comment: You could probably get away with using the `glob()` function instead of using File::Find::Rule. It should do the same thing in less space.

Comment: I could use glob, but glob can do strange things when file names have spaces in them. the recommendation these  days for Modern Perl is to use File::Find::Rule as far as I can make ok, its concise and meaningful.( Not to mention filters out directories ;) )

Comment: [ P.s. I tried to apply my knowledge here of good practices to make the code "good" and "easy to understand" and "Easy to maintain", as opposed to golfing it : )  ]

Comment: I can't imagine a lot of directories ending with ".php". I don't usually name files (especially programming ones) with spaces, but I can see how that is a valid concern.

Comment: Yes this new script seems better, although it converts <?xml to <?phpxml, so I still prefer my regular expression : $line =~ s/<\?(\s|\n|\t|[^a-zA-Z])/<?php$1/g;

Comment: Well yes, I was stating that  with the "you cant be certain its doing the right thing without an FSM parser" . I'mm fully aware of the string difficulties.

Comment: also, my case has been adapted so it will handle xml strings inside php assuming they are contiguous.

Comment: So far my tests have been positive with your script. Even in tricky cases.

Answer (score 2):

That's my version of the RegExp:

```
<\?(?!(php|=|xml))(\s|\t|\n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to streamline your regex for the purposes of this into what may work better, but I may be wrong since I haven't tested it on any real code.

Let's say you're sitting in the base directory of your code, you could start with:

```
find . -iname "*.php" -print0
```

That will get you all .php files, separated by NULL characters, which is necessary in case any of them have spaces.

```
find . -iname "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sed -n 's/\(<\?\)\([^a-zA-Z]\)/\1php\2/gp' '{}'
```

This should get you most of the way there. It will find all the files, then for each one, run sed to replace the code. However, without the -i tag (used below), this won't actually touch your files, it will just send your code to your terminal. The -n suppresses normal output, and the p after the regex part tells it to print only lines that changed.

Okay, if your results look correct, then you take the big step, which is replacing the files in-place. **You should definitely back up all your files before attempting this!!!**

```
find . -iname "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sed -i 's/\(<\?\)\([^a-zA-Z]\)/\1php\2/g' '{}'
```

That should about get the job done. Unfortunately, I have no PHP files lying around that use that syntax, so you're on your own to figure it out from here, but hopefully the mechanics of getting things done are a bit clearer now:

1. Grab all the files with "find"
2. Send that list of files to "xargs" (which does some command on the files one at a time
3. Use "sed" and the syntax 's/to-change/changed/' to put your regex magic to work!

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanations, I will definitely have a use for this on a few other problems I have!

Answer (score 1):

I used danorton script on almost 2000 files and it worked like a charm

I put his script into a file named "fixtags.php" and used the following linux 1 liner to solve the problem:

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs php fixtags.php --overwrite
```

the only problem I had is when it encountered a file that was zero bytes in size.

Comment: I used: ```php -d short_open_tag=On ~/scripts/replace_short_tags.php --overwrite *.php``` in the directory with all the troublesome scripts..

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.4 officially deprecates short open tags and PHP 8 removes them altogether, so this question on SO is going to get somewhat popular as people look for solutions to convert legacy codebases.

As already noted by other answers, sed doesn't cover all use-cases.  The suggested `full_opening_tag` PHP-CS-Fixer is very sed-like in its behavior and also doesn't cover all use-cases.  Also, at least one tool I found such as the one answer by danorton currently only works when short open tags are enabled, which if you upgraded to PHP 8 via an OS upgrade, you can't easily rollback to 7.x to run such tools.  Caveat Emptor very much applies with all of these approaches.

I have written a tool that does not depend on the existence of short open tags (i.e. it works with PHP 8), does not use regular expressions (i.e. it uses `token_get_all()`), and also avoids non-short open tags (e.g. `<?xml`) and other non-tag scenarios (e.g. PHP strings containing "tags").

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/php-short-open-tag-finder/

The default mode that the tool runs in just finds references and displays them.  No files are modified.

In `-ask` mode, which is currently the only mode that modifies files, the tool asks whether or not it is okay to replace each set of references on a per-file basis.  That is, if there are 500 files with 2,000 total short open tag references, it will only ask 500 times.

Even with file level grouping, the tool is perhaps overly cautious in its approach with making changes.  But we are talking about potentially modifying thousands of files on a system in a single day.  I don't think complete automation is the right answer here.  It only took me a few hours to go through and carefully consider every change spanned across a few thousand files on all the systems I manage with the tool.

I have quite a bit of experience with using `token_get_all()` as well as writing token parsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to go through this before and I found it best to do it in stages.  A bad script trying to catch it all can mess up a LOT of files.

I used Coda (or any other web editor) to do a simple find and replace on very specific strings.

For example starting with "

It may seem a little more tedious but I was confident that something wasn't getting messed up somewhere that I didn't know about. Going back is a real pain.

Comment: If going back is a real pain, you need proper version control. It shouldn't be.

Comment: That is what I did, commited to git then I'd like to use a script. (Kate did the job as you said, it supports "find in files" and then regex replacements one file at a time)

Comment: @derobert - True. At that time I didn't have any. I now have a proper SVN addiction.

Answer (score 0):

It's typical for XML/XHTML pages to include following code:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>
```

Of course that should not be changed neither to:

```
<?phpphp echo '<?phpxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>
```

nor:

```
<?php echo '<?phpxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>
```

Comment: Of course. The regexp I proposed in my question takes care of this. Kent Fedric also has a working regexp. And ax approach should be fine with it too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, automated solutions may not work. My recommendation:

1) Use grep to find all short tags:

```
grep -rn "<?[^p]" *
```

2) Go through each file and line and fix manually

I understand that this might not be a viable solution if you have a huge project, but for me it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I update php version.

Use this:

```
find . -iname "\*.ph\*" -type f -print0 |xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/<? /<?php /g' -e 's/<?\/\//<?php \/\//g' -e 's/<?\/\*/<?php \/\*/g' -e 's/<?\=/<?php echo/g'
```

This will convert "<?" to "<?php", "<?//" to "<?php //", "<?/*" to "<?php /*"

for any kind of file .php or .phtml

Credits: https://coderwall.com/p/cnm0_w/replace-php-short-open-tags-with-full-form-in-all-php-files-using-one-command

Comment: The php I was fixing needed an extra space after the echo: ``find . -iname "\*.ph\*" -type f -print0 |xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/<? /<?php /g' -e 's/<?\/\//<?php \/\//g' -e 's/<?\/\*/<?php \/\*/g' -e 's/<?\=/<?php echo /g'`` My code has things like ``<?=blah()?>``  and not ``<?= blah()?>``