# How do i convert php short tag to full one

Tags: php, shorttags

I am to edit a project of another guy who used php short tag everywhere in his script. I have short tag disabled in my server. I think converting all the short tags instead of enabling short tag in my server is the better one.

So which way to go better:

1. Converting All short tag?
2. Enabling short tag in my server?
3. How do i convert all short tag to full one in batch

Comment: http://www.emurasoft.com/replall/detail.htm

Comment: Just enable short tags. Why are they disabled in the first place?

Comment: and possible duplicate of [Batch script to replace PHP short open tags with <?php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/684587/367456)

Comment: @meagar because short tags are going away

Comment: if its just a few files just quickly run them through this http://convertphptags.online/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting can be written using http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php . Unlike find&replace, this does not affect XML declarations and so on.
Converting vs. enabling ST: It depends. Many programmers probably prefers <?php to <?, so when you convert, you code will be more "standard". However, the importancy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/of "standard"-way depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

For others, KoolKabin is referring to the use of `<?` instead of `<?php` as the opening tag for php code, usually used in this abbreviated form:

```
<?= $myvar1, $myvar2 ?>
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
<? echo $myvar1, $myvar2 ?>
```

Which is itself equivalent to this, when the server is so configured with **short_open_tag = on** in php.ini:

```
<?php echo $myvar1, $myvar2 ?>
```

Personally, I’d convert all the short tags unless there are many pages that have nothing but short tags.

Writing some code around [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) is your safest bet (as I detail in a separate answer here), but you might be able to get away with a simple **sed** script:

```
sed -e 's/<?\([ \t\r]\)/<?php\1/g' \
    -e 's/<?$/<?php/g' \
    -e 's/<?=\([ \t\r]\)\?/<?php echo \1/g'
```

Just beware of strings in your code (regexes, particularly) that might have the **`<?`** sequence followed by a whitespace character. See also: [Useful one-line scripts for sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt), where it’s pointed out that **sed** syntax varies, and that some don’t support the `\t` code (but you can type in an actual tab character).

n.b. Beware that **sed** doesn’t use Perl regexes and at least one of the other replies here has invalid **sed** syntax: e.g. `\?` in Perl is a literal question mark, but he intends `?`, which is a literal question mark in **sed**. (He also replaces `<?=` with `<?php`, incorrectly omitting the “echo”.)

Answer (score 2):

I looked a little more and I modify my earlier answer to: “definitely convert it”. It’s easy with the PHP-CLI converter below. Make sure that the system you run this on is configured with `short_open_tag=on`.

```
#!php-cli
<?php
global $argv;

$contents = file_get_contents($argv[1]) or die;
$tokens = token_get_all($contents);
$tokens[] = array(0x7E0F7E0F,"",-1);

foreach($tokens as $ix => $token) {
  if(is_array($token)) {
    list($toktype, $src) = $token;
    if ($toktype == T_OPEN_TAG) {
      if (($src == "<?") && ($tokens[$ix+1][0] != T_STRING)) {
        $src = "<?php";
        if ($tokens[$ix+1][0] != T_WHITESPACE) {
          $src .= " ";
        }
      }
    }
    else if($toktype == T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO) {
      $src = "<?php echo";
      if($tokens[$ix+1][0] != T_WHITESPACE) {
        $src .= " ";
      }
    }
    print $src;
  }
  else {
    print $token;
  }
}
```

Comment: On my blog I posted a more complete version with comments and an option to preserve <?= tags, changing only <? tags:
http://www.danielnorton.com/2010/09/1079/converter-to-replace-php-short-open-tags-shorttags-with-long-tags

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Eclipse PDT, using it's search and replace all within a project (CTRL + H) to replace all short tags with full tags.

Comment: Or any other good IDE, like NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the server configuration would probably be faster. I personally wouldn't bother to search and replace, because, even though I prefer using normal tags, it's just a matter of taste. Short tags conflicting with XML declarations is not a serious issue, as you can just put the declarations inside strings.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely relpace the tags.

If your code is on a Unix/Linux/posix then something like:

```
find ${BASEDIR} -iname \*.php -exec rep_sht_tags.sh {} \;
```

where rep_sht_tags.sh contains something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

destdir=`dirname $1`
mkdir -p /backup/${destdir}

cp $1 /backup/$1
sed 's/<\?=/<?php /' /backup/$1 >$1
```

(NB not tested)

Comment: "Definitely relpace the tags" Can you elaborate on your reasoning?

Comment: Short tags are deprecated for good reason - they are used elsewhere for other purposes

Comment: That's up for debate.  What do you mean "used elsewhere for other purposes"?