# Finding all PHP short tags

Tags: php, regex, vim

I need to find all short PHP tags.

The regex for it `<\?(?!php)` but I can not use it in vim.

How to "convert" it to vim?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684587/batch-script-to-replace-php-short-open-tags-with-php

Comment: No, because file can have something like '<?echo "foo" ?>'

Comment: Just be careful not to replace `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` headers, if you have any.

Comment: This regex works in notepad++ search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to find short-tags in vim is to find all occurrences of `<?` not followed by a `p`:

```
/<?[^p]
```

The reason your regex is failing in vim is because `/?` finds literal question marks, while `\?` is a quantifier; `/<\?` in vim will attempt to find 0 or 1 less-than signs. This is backwards from what you might expect in most regular expression engines.

---

If you want to match short tags that are immediately followed by a new line, you cannot use `[^p]`, which requires there to be *something* there to match which isn't a `p`. In this case, you can match "not p or end-of-line" with

```
/<?\($\|[^p]\)
```

Comment: +1 for the good idea I just use it in Eclipse with <\?[^p] for restoring an old php project.

Comment: dont forget about valid <?= <?xml tags!! 
better use <\?[^p=x] and <\?$ for searching. second term will find <? with newline at the end ...

Answer (score 32):

For me this one worked fine:

```
<\?(?!php|xml)
```

Comment: Work with Geany!

Comment: And also for copy and pasteable in grepWin

Comment: I used <\?(?!php|xml|=) so I could exclude <?=

Answer (score 10):

#### Find

```
<\?(\t|\n|\s)
```

#### Replace

```
<?php$1
```

#### Explanation

Match *only* short tags `<\?`, followed by white-space, tab or newline `(\t|\n|\s)` and store it in `$1`

All of the solutions provided here match what the line *doesn't* contain, instead of what we know it will be guaranteed to contain. This allows your code formatting to remain identical, only adding the text `php` where needed.

We only ever want to match the short tag, and shouldn't care what comes after (php/xml/= etc). This find/replace will match both inline short tags and short tags on a separate line.

**Note:** If you're using Windows line-breaks, `<\?(\t|\r\n|\s)` will match the same.

Answer (score 9):

Using (a recent version of) `grep`:

```
grep -P '<\?(?!(php|xml|=))' *
```

To find all files with a `<?` short tag:

```
find -type f -exec grep -IlP '<\?(?!(php|xml|=))' {} +
```

Note that these do not match the `<?=` short tag, as that is [always available](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) since 5.4.0 and it does no harm either way. (Whereas `<?` does harm if `allow_short_tags = Off`.)

Comment: Note that this will also include binary files (pictures, fonts). To only search through PHP source code, use grep with `--include=*.php` flag. Be aware that your server may also execute files with other extensions (.phtml, .php5). To include those, repeat the flag for each extension.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! The regexp perfectly in PhpStorm and other IDEs and ignores short echo tags ```<?=``` which the other solutions have a flaw to as they pick the short echo tags up when they are not considered by PHP as a short opening tag, and are enabled by default! Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

The correct look ahead pattern you are after is `<?\(php\)\@!` that will match all short tags except those followed by `php`

For more details on look ahead/behind assertions just type `:help \@` in vim

Comment: @Liam For `grep` version, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40915605/2908724

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification to the answer by Fredrik Pihl

```
/<?[^p\n]
```

The above answer didn't match an opening short tag followed by a newline that was hidden in some code I was looking at, this one does...

Answer (score 1):

To match `<?` and not `<?php`  just use this as a search term in vim:

```
/<?[^p]
```

`/` to start the search in cmd-mode

Comment: He's specifically looking to match `<?` but not `<?php`

Comment: I have to find only short tags.

Answer (score 1):

I want to replace all `<?` tags to `<?php` in PhpStorm by find and replace.

For me works this

find

```
<\?[^p](.*)
```

replace

```
<?php\n$1
```

I'm using `$1` to add \n after php tag, otherwise it replace all sting with `<?`

Comment: in PHPStorm 9, this attempts to replace xml tags and short echos as well

Comment: you can choose to search only in *.php files.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will only catch `<?`

```
<\?(?!php|xml|=)
```

If you also want to catch `<?=` then use this instead:

```
<\?(?!php|xml)
```